# Elastic Net: diverging number of parameters

Tags: model-selection, lasso, elastic-net, regularization

I am reading the paper [On The Adaptive Elastic-Net With a Diverging Number of Parameters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4-96S3fjlAhWmPOwKHSExBCcQFjABegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusers.stat.umn.edu%2F~zouxx019%2FPapers%2Faenet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1nzYr_ovgpcB7Dnr8brqnW) by Zou and Zhang (2009). I found it while I was researching the lasso and elastic net in general and I am confused by the terminology of "diverging number of parameters". I have not come across it in previous literature on the lasso/elastic net. So far I understand it to possibly mean the following, based on the abstract of this related [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi7k8Oa4PjlAhWP-KQKHZpVDhQQFjADegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Forfe.princeton.edu%2F~jqfan%2Fpapers%2F02%2Fmodsel.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1ArsK2eBK56xDRtZ8tBcmh):

- The number of parameters to be fit by the model can be very large (tend towards $\infty$)

> "They demonstrated that this class of procedures has an oracle property
>   when the number of parameters is finite. However, in most model
>   selection problems the number of parameters should be large and grow
>   with the sample size. In this paper some
>   asymptotic properties of the nonconcave penalized likelihood are established
>   for situations in which the number of parameters tends to $\infty$ as the sample
>   size increases."

With the quote being from the above mentioned abstract.
Is my understanding of the terminology correct?